Signing an XML using python
I'm trying to sign an XML and verify the signature with the following code:
import signxml
from lxml import etree

root = etree.parse('...')
with open('...', 'r') as f:
    cert = f.read()
with open('...', 'r') as f:
    key = f.read()
signer = signxml.XMLSigner(
    method=signxml.methods.enveloped,
    c14n_algorithm='http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments'
)
signer.namespaces = {None: signxml.namespaces.ds}
signed_root = signer.sign(root, key=key, cert=cert)
signxml.XMLVerifier().verify(signed_root, ca_pem_file='...').signed_xml

and the last row throws the exception:
Signature verification failed: bad signature
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/signxml/__init__.py", line 849, in verify
    verify(signing_cert, raw_signature, signed_info_c14n, signature_digest_method)
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 3235, in verify
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 57, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('rsa routines', '', 'bad signature'), ('Provider routines', '', 'RSA lib')]

But if I remove signer.namespaces = {None: signxml.namespaces.ds}, the verifications passes successfully. However I must keep signer.namespaces = {None: signxml.namespaces.ds} because in my case the the signature tag must be without any namespace. Please help with this.

If I read the rules the signature must use the namespace.
